# Is the phrase "fitting (someone) in (to a schedule)" all right to use or is there a better way to say this?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, idioms

*fit* (someone) *in* (to a schedule)

Is this phrase useful for scheduling meetings and appointments. When you're talking to someone with a busy schedule, you may have to ask them to "fit you in". "Fitting you in" means fitting you into their schedule. You can imagine a schedule book with each meeting or appointment taking up a block of time. If the person has enough room to add your appointment between two other appointments, then you say that they could "fit you in".

I guess it's an idiom, but it doesn't seem as though this is the best way to ask for someone to "pencil you in."

Comment: "To pencil in" and "to fit in" are different: **To pencil [someone or something] in** = to make a *provisional* appointment - the idea behind this is that writing that is done with a pencil can be easily erased, and thus the time of the appointment can be easily changed. **To fit [someone or something] in**, implies a request or offer that is between two other appointments, etc. This use is a figurative use of "to fit" = to place something accurately and/or within the space/volume between other objects: e.g. "Do these shoes fit your foot?" or. "You can fit that piece of the jigsaw in here."

Comment: "I'll see if I can fit you into my schedule" sounds more impersonal, dismissive, than "I'll see if I can fit you in". "Have you any free time tomorrow?" or "Have you a gap in your diary tomorrow?"  are perhaps better hedged requests.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is ok to use.

You could use:

`I can schedule you for (Date/Time)` or

`We can schedule a meeting for (Date/Time)`

to be more formal.

Comment: On what authority is your answer based? Please read the Help on answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic way (and more appropriate/self-evident in case of a *busy schedule*) is to use ***squeeze*** instead of *fit*.

> Can you ***squeeze*** me **into** your schedule?

TFD(idioms):

> **[squeeze into](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squeeze+into)**
>   *v*.
>   1. To manage to make room or time for someone or something in some tight space or schedule by or as if by exerting pressure:
>   The
>   dentist can squeeze you into her schedule next week.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. Copyright © 2005
>   by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton
>   Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Comment: Isn't 'squeeze into' more informal?

Comment: Why do you think “squeeze” is better than “fit”. The latter is plain English. Why would you suggest a more idiomatic way of speaking?  Expressing an opinion without justification is not an acceptable way to answer on this list.

Comment: @David, that's not exactly my _opinion_; I've backed it up with a dictionary entry including an example usage appropriate to the context. And by the way, I respect your opinion.